# Coloring all elements in prime ordered sets amongst a set of sets

Tags: color

So I have a set of sets. I want only those sets whose order amongst the sets plus one is prime to be colored (all the same, anything but the standard black). Any ideas?

ArrayPlot[{{1}, {1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {1,1,1,1}}] is what it looks like now. there are 4 sets within. I want those sets with an order + 1 (meaning starting from 2 ascending to 5) to be colored differently for being equal to a prime. therefore the 3rd set is the only row of the arrayplot that should be black. the rest should be another color, all the same color. I am reading set order from left to right being equivocal to ascending order.

Comment: You can add those details to the question to make it self-contained.

Comment: I tried executing just that and was returned a blank image. I'm not sure where I would be inserting my boolean data.

Comment: Sorry, don't have time now to parse this. Try to [format your question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) properly and I'm sure you will get the answer you need.

Comment: It's the same thing except by skipping sets (I think the command is something like ;; ;;) and excluding 0's of the two elements possible (the other being 1)

Comment: As with {Range[2, 6][[;; ;; 2]]}

Comment: @Kuba - Better phrasing of the question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/72270/24872